# smarty phpunit empty fetch

Tags: phpunit, smarty, fetch

I need help please.

I'm using Smarty with PHPUnit, and I have troubles.

For example:

In some checks, I call fetch function many times, and I only receive right the first call, the others only return empty. Why???

I let some code here as an example:

```
     /**
     * @dataProvider provider_test
     */
   public function test_field($field) {

                // with this I instance smarty
      $front = $this->get_template();

      $front->assign('function', 'fb_user_field');
      $front->assign('field', $field);

                // this fetch only return right widh the first value of field
      $result = $front->fetch('tests/generic.tpl');

      $this->assertNotNull($result);
   }

   public function provider_test() {

      return array(
         array('field' => 'subdomain'),
         array('field' => 'login')
      );
   }
```

I check $field and in every iteration receive the correct value, but after the first one, fetch return only empty.

Why???? Thanks!!!

Comment: You need to show us the function get_template().

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use the MakeGood or similar to step by step debug your php code. Otherwise it is guess and check till you die!

Here's some links

http://blog.loftdigital.com/running-phpunit-tests-in-eclipse-pdt

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qnWL52wt58

I used to spend hours guess and check with phpunit until I discovered MakeGood. Hope it helps!